# minimize a list of items to one item in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have a form.There's different parts in that form.Every part is separated by a heading.What i want to achieve is when i click on the heading,the items under it will disappear.
i'll show what i want to do

[wanted design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWtRA.png)

As you see there's a minimize button.when clicked the button will change to a maximize button.A plus sign

Here's what i made so far
[my design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMfDt.png)

I really don't know how to make this.i suppose some kind of css

Thank you for any help

Comment: Salut, did you tried something ? The part with the show /hide items is pretty easy . I think you question is only about css

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO i didn't try anything.i wanted to get a direction first.now i know it's pretty easy and doable in css only not angularjs.i thought about using ng-if but now i won't.thank you.i'll keep the question open so i can edit  it when i get something

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO Solved it by using jquery slidetoggle.i did use css too.thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using jquery SlideToggle

```
  $(".buttonh").click(function(){
if($(this).html() == "-"){
    $(this).html("+");
}
else{
    $(this).html("-");
}
$("#ion-item2").slideToggle();
});
```

You'll need to add jquery in index.html